# Citrix font errors on Fedora 13/14

Tags: vpn, fedora, citrix, virtual-desktop

I need to run Citrix Receiver on Fedora 13 to connect into a corporate VPN. I had it running originally on Fedora13, but after some previous update some time ago in the past, Citrix stopped working. Now, when opening the application, the dialogue appears but no text is visible.

If attempting to run the application from the command-line, there is a repeating error that occurs:

```
Warning: 
    Name: FONTLIST_DEFAULT_TAG_STRING
    Class: XmRendition
    Conversion failed.  Cannot load font.

Warning: No font found.
```

I found one way around this, by specifying a variable in terminal by doing the following:

```
export LANG=C
/usr/lib/ICAClient/wfcmg
```

This opens Citrix receiver with some level of font rendering. This does not however help whilst trying to access the network through the receiver itself.

Has anyone had a similar issue? I have seen lots of people suffering at this problem online but limited help to resolve this. Any help appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
I have just upgraded to Fedora 14 and the same error still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of a work colleague, @marek:

```
rpm -e sazanami-mincho-fonts --nodeps
```

Seems like you need to remove this font-set too. Also the cjkuni font-pack has to go as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get this working, though this is not a glamorous or long-term fix.

From the point above, setting the "LANG" = "C" allows Citrix to open up from the Applications menu but not from a (.ica) link in Firefox. I found a post that suggested running Firefox from the command-line and, when doing this, Citrix will open from the link.

```
bash# export LANG=C
bash# firefox
```

I would still like to find the proper solution... thanks.